# DisplayEventReceiver.java crash Android

Tags: android, kotlin, logging, crash, crashlytics

I am facing a crash issue with thousands of users impacted and got the following log for main thread in crashlytics :

I am unable to find any cause of this issue. Any idea about this ?

```
main (runnable):tid=1 systid=17039 
#00 pc 0x53a6e0 libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool) + 128)
#01 pc 0x6f0e04 libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const + 236)
#02 pc 0x6fe690 libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*) + 208)
#03 pc 0x40295c libart.so (art::Thread::RunCheckpointFunction() + 140)
#04 pc 0x5606d4 libart.so (artQuickGenericJniEndTrampoline + 844)
#05 pc 0x440564 libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline + 164)
#06 pc 0x2d24368 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.Choreographer.scheduleVsyncLocked + 200)
#07 pc 0x2d2412c memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.Choreographer.scheduleFrameLocked + 1516)
#08 pc 0x2d22f1c memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.Choreographer.postCallbackDelayedInternal + 236)
#09 pc 0x2e3c2e4 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.ViewRootImpl.scheduleTraversals + 980)
#10 pc 0x2e38158 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals + 16600)
#11 pc 0x2e24a54 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal + 724)
#12 pc 0x2e14ec0 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run + 64)
#13 pc 0x2d2120c memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks + 812)
#14 pc 0x2d21cd8 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.Choreographer.doFrame + 1592)
#15 pc 0x2d205ac memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run + 92)
#16 pc 0x2069330 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 80)
#17 pc 0x2b3f894 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.os.Looper.loopOnce + 1060)
#18 pc 0x2087310 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.os.Looper.loop + 576)
#19 pc 0x25cb6c4 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.app.ActivityThread.main + 2052)
#20 pc 0x436e00 libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub + 576)
#21 pc 0x469534 libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long) + 1960)
#22 pc 0x468d64 libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*) (.__uniq.165753521025965369065708152063621506277) + 48)
#23 pc 0x440554 libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline + 148)
#24 pc 0x3035cb8 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 136)
#25 pc 0x20b0d4 libart.so (nterp_helper + 7636)
#26 pc 0x33e974 framework.jar (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 716)
#27 pc 0x436e00 libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub + 576)
#28 pc 0x582718 libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list) + 900)
#29 pc 0x5f611c libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list) + 160)
#30 pc 0xb0b28 libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...) + 120)
#31 pc 0xbc2bc libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool) + 980)
#32 pc 0x2580 app_process64 (main + 1320)
#33 pc 0x48a00 libc.so (__libc_init + 96)
       at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.nativeScheduleVsync(DisplayEventReceiver.java)
       at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.scheduleVsync(DisplayEventReceiver.java:252)
       at android.view.Choreographer.scheduleVsyncLocked(Choreographer.java:1024)
       at android.view.Choreographer.scheduleFrameLocked(Choreographer.java:767)
       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallbackDelayedInternal(Choreographer.java:552)
       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallbackDelayed(Choreographer.java:535)
       at android.view.Choreographer.postCallback(Choreographer.java:507)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scheduleTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2341)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3671)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2383)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9307)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1186)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:986)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:912)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1171)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8396)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

Tried to check DisplayEventReceiver related issues, didn't get anything.

Comment: File>InvalideteChche >restart

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the issue, the issue is not for me as a developer but to the end users.
I got the log from Firebase crashlytics.